# What are the laws on showing another company's logo in my book on branding?

Tags: united-kingdom, trademark

I am writing a book on best practice branding for entrepreneurs and want to demonstrate my points using well-known (as well as our own client) logos.

The logos will be used for illustrative, educational purposes and shown in a good light. I can put a line at the start of the book explaining that the use of the logo does not imply any endorsement or sponsorship from these brands.

Will this be enough?